# Launching website from Android toolbar

Tags: android

I have the following code in my menu.xml:

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/goToWebsite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            case R.id.more:
                goToUrl("http://www.example.com");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

the case `R.id.more` is not executed:

```
goToUrl("http://www.example.com");
                return true;

private void goToUrl (String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }
```

What's wrong?

**Update:**

Toasing under r.id.more not working aswelel:

```
case R.id.more:
                Toast.makeText(this,"TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: check my answer

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create Menu.xml file in menu folder in res directory like as:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


            <item
                android:id="@+id/common_menu_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/settings"
                android:title="@string/settings"
               app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />  
           <item
                android:id="@+id/more"
                android:title="@string/goToWebsite"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

override on onOptionsItemSelected() in Activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.common_menu_settings:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
            case R.id.more:
                goToUrl("http://www.example.com");
                break;

     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

i hope its useful to you:)
Happy Coding:)

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        case R.id.more:
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,   

Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));

startActivity(browserIntent);
            return true;
             break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you like tell us what's the different? why would you have return true & break ? wouldn't that actually give compiling error?